# Is there a way to construct x_mono_curve by 2 one root points? (circular boolean arrangments)

Tags: cgal

I did see a constructor for x_mono_curve needs 2 one root points and one rational supporting line:
X_monotone_curve_2 (const typename Kernel::Line_2 &line, const Point_2 &source, const Point_2 &target)

Or an overrides is 2 rational points:

X_monotone_curve_2 (const typename Kernel::Point_2 &source, const typename Kernel::Point_2 &target)

Is there a way to construct x_mono_curve by source and target? how to calculate rational supporting line in this case?

Thank you

Comment: Did you see [that page](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Arrangement_on_surface_2/classCGAL_1_1Arr__circle__segment__traits__2_1_1X__monotone__curve__2.html)? Note that in general if you have points with algebraic coordinates, the line joining them is not rational.

Comment: Hi sloriot,  yes, I saw that page, the requirement comes from translate a x mono curve for a rational x, y a little. looks 2 one root points' CoordNT can be use operator+ to offset. But its support_ling line need re-construct. This is a requirement to using boolean 2d package, offset the polygon a little.

Comment: Sorry, more explain on this: I want implement a feature that, can offset a circular arc (x mono curve) into a generic polygon. I think offset arc's source, target one root point is possible(one root point + rational vector). re-construct 2 side arcs is possible(modify the support circle), at last it need connect/construct 2 offset one root points as line segment, is that possible?